# Does PHP's array equality require elements in the same order?

Tags: php, arrays

According to http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php:

```
$a == $b    Equality    TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs.
$a === $b   Identity    TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same types.
```

As such, I would have expected these two arrays to have equality, but they do not.

```
$a1=array('a','b');
$a2=array('b','a');
echo(($a1==$a2)?'equal':'not equal');
```

I could sort the arrays first and they have both equality and identity.

Am I misinterpreting the PHP manual? Does PHP's array equality require elements in the same order?

EDIT.  The posted answers perfectly answered the question.  Possible workarounds include the following.  While not part of my original question, any recommendations on the best way to implement would be appreciated.

```
<?php
$a1=array('a','b');
$a2=array('b','a');
echo((($a1==$a2)?'equal':'not equal').'<br>');
echo(((array_diff($a1, $a2) === array_diff($a2, $a1))?'equal':'not equal').'<br>');
sort($a1);
sort($a2);
echo((($a1==$a2)?'equal':'not equal').'<br>');
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
not equal
equal
equal
```

Comment: maybe if you sorted them first, before comparing them (not tried it, but seems to be the first thing that came to mind) [for anyone that doesn't know how - http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php]

Comment: Yes, sorting will work.  But so did Lauri's answer (she later removed it).  I will amend my original post for other's reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's Because:

In the first array it's:

```
0 => a
1 => b
```

And in the second array it's:

```
0 => b
1 => a
```

So the `values` and the `keys` are the same, but not as `pair`!

So if you change the keys in the second array it's `TRUE` because the value and the key's are the same as pair:

```
$a1 = array('a','b');
$a2 = array( 1 =>'b', 0 =>'a');
echo(($a1==$a2)?'equal':'not equal');
```

Output:

```
equal
```

Comment: Ah, I see!  Not the same pair!  This was driving me crazy, but now I see the obvious.

Comment: @user1032531 Yeah it can be a bit confusing! Nice that i could help you

Answer (score 1):

Its a good question but as the docs mention. It needs the same key value pairs. Your first array is `1 => a` and your second is `2=>a`

Same for b. So therefore not equal.

An example would be

```
$a=array('a'=>'a','b'=>'b');
$a=array('b=>'b','a'=>'a');
```